# Simple PHP Login URL not connecting with code

Tags: php

I have been trying to make working php code which will return `"1"`.

As well the database information is all removed, but is accurate since I get no `"3"` error.

Example being: `www.mysite.com/login.php/?test=itemindatabase`

and if `"itemindatabase"` is found in the database, then it will return "1"

A few notes:

`login` is the name of the table.

`test` is the name of the only column (other than `id`)

```
<?php 
 $host = "localhost";  
 $username = "";  
 $password = "";  
 $database = "";  

      $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
      $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
           if(empty($_POST["test"]))  
           {  
                die("3");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE test = :test";  
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'test'     =>     $_POST["test"]  
                     )  
                );  
                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                     die("1"); //success!
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     die("0"); //fail not found
                }  
        }

?>
```

I have only been getting "0" every try which means failure.

Comment: Change this `$_POST["test"]` to this `$_GET["test"]`.

Comment: Still happens to return 0 on the webpage.

Comment: I don't think you can query a table without connecting with the Database it exist. Your database variable is empty. Give a appropriate database name and make sure error reporting is on in your server during the development

Comment: @Kuru I should have said this in the original thread and I will. But I removed that information since it is personal.

Comment: I think you should use mysqli instead of mysql. It's good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things:-

1.Your all db credentials are empty? if you removed them because of security issue then Ok. Otherwise please provide valid and correct values there.Otherwise connection itself will not create.

2.`$_POST["test"]` need to be  `$_GET["test"]`

3.`array('test'=>$_POST["test"])` need to be `array(':test'=>$_POST["test"])`

Check this code and try:-

```
<?php

 //comment these two lines when code started working fine
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors',1);

 $host = "localhost";  
 $username = "";  //check and provide valid value
 $password = "";  //check and provide valid value
 $database = "";  //this can't be empty in any case

    try {
        $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

           if(!empty($_GET['test'])){
                $statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE test = :test");  
                $statement->execute(array(':test'=>$_GET["test"]));  
                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                     echo "record found successfully";
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     echo "no record found";
                }  

           }else{
             echo "Please provide input value";
           }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
?>
```

Note:- [How to fetch records](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: I modified the original description. All the database information is in the actual script but I removed due to privacy. And thank you for your answer. But I am still getting a return of "0"

Comment: Yes I have. thanks for the answer as I am sure it has helped me to further fixing this issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a quick question. How would I make it print the correct input back using this code? ie: a row in the database was "found" and it will print found on the page

Comment: @JohanDoe  Instead of asking everything try to learn from php manual or w3school. Check this manual for help:- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php